# C drive free space drops very fast with no obvious reason

Tags: windows

My operating system is Windows 10 and I have a problem with the free space dropping for no reason.
A couple of days ago I ran a python code in jupyter notebook, and in the middle of the execution my C drive ran out of space (there was ~50 GB free space), and since then the C drive free space changes significantly (even shrinks to few MBs) without no obvious reason.
Since then I found some huge files in a pycharm temporary directory, and I freed 47GB of space, but after a short time, it runs out of space again ( I am not even running any code anymore)!
When I restart, the free space gradually starts to increase, and again after a some time, it shrinks to a few GB or even MBs.

PS. I installed WinDirStat to show me the stat of the disk space, and it shows 93 GB under this path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Files\Windows.edb, but I can't open Data folder in the file explorer, and it shows 0 bytes when I open the folder properties.

Answer (score 0):

`Windows.edb` is an index database of the Windows Search function. It provides data to speed up searching in the file system due to indexing of files. There are several guides in the internet about reducing it's size. The radical way would be deleting it but I do not recomment this. You had to turn Windows Search off to do so:

```
net stop "Windows Search"
del %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb
net start "Windows Search"
```

You wrote in your question that the file suddenly grew while your program was running. Maybe files will be created there. These files should be set to [not be indexed](https://superuser.com/questions/591406/how-do-i-disable-indexing-in-a-specific-directory-across-multiple-platforms). You should do that for the folder where the files are created. If this all fails, you could finally [turn indexing off](https://superuser.com/questions/73204/correct-way-to-disable-indexing-in-windows-7) which slows down Windows Search.

Comment: I have the same problem and have tried numerous solutions. Nothing has worked to date. I will check the Windows Search. This is a common problem and a solution would be most welcome.